# Rails + Angular dynamic images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, vue.js, sprockets

Everyone's saying, that `.erb` for JavaScript is a bad practice. Then how do I solve this very common problem:

```
<img ng-src='images/{{ some_ng_model.img_name }}.png'>
```

Then somewhere in the code image changes:

```
$scope.some_ng_model.img_name = 'new_img'
```

This of course will not work because sprockets precompile assets.

Till now I've been putting those images in `public` directory, so they are not precompiled and I can access them with their original names.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `src`, use `v-bind:src="'images/' + some_ng_model.img_name + '.png"'`

Comment: If you are using vuejs that is... I see the vue tag but that looks like you're using angular...

Comment: I do use `:src` in Vue.js and `ng-src` in Angular, but that's not solving the original problem – accessing images after they are being precompiled by Rails` sprockets